# What Brezhnev sites are there in Moscow?

Tags: museums, history, moscow, artworks

Apart from his statutes in the MUZEON park, the plaque on his former apartment building, and his grave at the Kremlin Wall Necropolis, are there any public monuments, sites, or museum exhibits in Moscow dedicated to Leonid Brezhnev?

I know that last year the Russian State Archives put together [a retrospective exhibition for the 109th anniversary of Brezhnev's birth](https://www.dawn.com/news/1241677).  Is this exhibition still open?  If not, are there any galleries or historical museums in the city that dedicate a significant amount of material to him?  (I don't recall seeing any portraits of him in the Institute of Russian Realist Art.)

Comment: http://archives.ru/exhibitions/2015-bregnev_press.shtml - the exhibition ended in Feb 2016.

Answer (score 3):

There are no sites dedicated to Brezhnev as far as I know (quick web search doesn't return anything interesting).

There's "Brezhnev house" with apartment for him, but he never moved in. http://nicolaitroitsky.livejournal.com/4562211.html

There's a house somewhere on Kutuzovsky prospect where he actually resided.

There's a lot of Brezhnevist architecture all over the Moscow, especially if you go outside city center (trivial to do with Metro). My favourite one is probably Paleontology museum http://www.paleo.ru/museum/about/ But really, there's a lot.

You can probably find more dedicated sites in his pre-Moscow locations.
Kamenskoe, present-day Ukraine? Samara? Kazakhstan?

UPD: I wanted to remind also that Росархив, which held this exhibition now expired, is actually an archive. You can probably go there and poke in the same documents which were exhibited.

UPD 2: Another place to consider is iconic Жигули beer bar on Новый Арбат (which itself is a huge Brezhnevist monument).
It features a wall photo of Breznhev partying. https://yandex.ru/maps/-/C6fcVIO5 for street view